# Is it just as effective to mix fat in at the end of a curry?

Tags: curry, mixing, fat

I usually cook low fat curry i.e with fat removed.  Since we still need fat before eating the curry I melt a bit of premade tallow in the microwave then I add the curry to  it and mix.

I'm wondering if this mixing is good enough o get the flavour of the curry into the fat.  It certainly looks mixed i.e I can no longer see white tallow but everyhthing is orange from the spices.

Im wondering if the flavours infuse into the fat properly or of its better to add if this is important to me, if I should add the fat at the beginning? chemically how are the two different if they result in a different outcome, taste etc?

Comment: I would suggest that you try it both ways and see what the differences are, if any, and decide which you like best.

Comment: I'm wondering what is the point of cooking a "low fat curry" then adding fat. It's had no real chance to blend flavours or cook in at all, yet the end result is just as "fattening".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When a recipe asks to add spices to the oil, can you add the spices directly to the sauce for the same effect?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/87360/when-a-recipe-asks-to-add-spices-to-the-oil-can-you-add-the-spices-directly-to)

Comment: The duplicate I've suggested looks at things from a slightly different point of view, but explains why  the fat is added at the beginning. I started to write an answer to this question and it was going to be too similar to my answer to that older question

Answer (score 1):

Fat helps carry flavor, it also add to the mouth-feel of the final product.  Fat also adds flavor.  So, getting the "flavor into the fat", or probably better put, to be carried by the fat, is only part of the equation. So, in part this depends on why the fat is necessary for a particular dish.  There are all types of curries, so clarifying your recipe and purpose would be helpful in, at least partly, answering this question.  As @Cindy points out in the comments, since you are adding this at the end, it would be easy to reserve some of your product without the extra fat added, and compare it with the final product once the fat is added.  See which you like better.